# Excluding a string in a regex expression

Tags: python, regex

I currently have the following regular expression:

```
/(_|[a-z]|[A-Z])(_|[a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9])*/
```

I would like the expression not to match with "PI", however I failed to do so.
To clarify, I would like the following to be valid:
_PI, abcPI, PIpipipi
I just dont want to accept PI when its on its own.

Comment: So do you want more than two characters? or is it only `PI` that you want to exclude?

Comment: Maybe `r"\b(?!PI\b)[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*"`? See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z4GOQj/1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before jumping at the solution, please have a look at your regex: the character classes for single ranges inside alternation groups is an inefficient way of writing regex patterns. You may simply merge these `([A-Z]|[0-9]|_)+` into `[A-Z0-9_]+`.

The solution may be a word boundary with a negative lookahead after it:

```
r"\b(?!PI\b)[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z4GOQj/1). You may replace `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` with `\w`:

```
re.compile(r"\b(?!PI\b)[_a-zA-Z]\w*")          # In Python 2.x, re.UNICODE is not enabled by default
re.compile(r"\b(?!PI\b)[_a-zA-Z]\w*", re.A)    # In Python 3.x, make \w match ASCII only
```

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?!PI\b)` - immediately to the right, there can't be `PI` as a whole word
- `[_a-zA-Z]` - an ASCII letter or `_`
- `[_a-zA-Z0-9]*` - 0 or more underscores, ASCII letters or digits.

Answer (score 0):

Submitting another answer:
`^(((?!PI).)*)$|^.*(PI).+$|^.+(PI).*$`

I broke it down into 3 cases using OR `|`:

1) Match a string that doesn't contain PI at all.

```
^(((?!PI).)*)$
```

2) Match a string that has PI in it but has at least one character behind it, and optionally any characters ahead of it.

```
^.*(PI).+$
```

3) Match a string that has PI in it but has at least one character ahead of it, and optionally any characters behind it.

```
^.+(PI).*$
```

Here it is with test cases:
https://regex101.com/r/7rzqpe/3

Please comment if you find a missing edge case.

Answer (score 0):

Not very nice, but I'll add it anyway for variety:

```
/^([A-OQ-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*|P([A-HJ-Za-z0-9_][A-Za-z0-9_]*)?)$/
```